Try to authenticate using PassKeys using SimpleWebAuthn package, React and Nodejs
I'm trying to authenticate user using passkey, at the VerifyAuthenticateResponse method, I faced an issue of no getting logged in, instead the server thrown this kind of error which I didn't exepected. Firstly I thought, the data is stored in mongodb so let's convert back to normal js format then too it didn't work. The attribute passkey stored in mongodb is of type Mixed.
exports.loginVerification = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, credential } = req.body;
    if (!username || !credential) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: "Username and credential are required",
      });
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ username }).select("-password");
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: "User not found",
      });
    }

    const challenge = await Challenge.findOne({ userId: user._id });
    if (!challenge) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: "Challenge not found",
      });
    }

    const userObject = user.toObject();
    const credentialId = userObject.passkey.credentialID;
    const credentialPublicKey = userObject.passkey.credentialPublicKey;
    const counter = userObject.passkey.counter;

    console.log({
      passkey: userObject.passkey,
    });

    const result = await verifyAuthenticationResponse({
      expectedOrigin: process.env.ORIGIN,
      expectedRPID: process.env.RP_ID,
      response: credential,
      expectedChallenge: challenge.challenge,
      authenticator: userObject.passkey,
    });

    console.log({ result });

    if (!result.verified) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: "Verification failed",
      });
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      verified: result.verified,
      message: "Verification successful",
      user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
};

Getting an error as -
Error: No data
    at Object.decodePartialCBOR (D:\fullstack\passkey-authentication\server\node_modules\@levischuck\tiny-cbor\script\cbor\cbor.js:355:15)
    at Object.decodeFirst (D:\fullstack\passkey-authentication\server\node_modules\@simplewebauthn\server\script\helpers\iso\isoCBOR.js:25:40)
    at decodeCredentialPublicKey (D:\fullstack\passkey-authentication\server\node_modules\@simplewebauthn\server\script\helpers\decodeCredentialPublicKey.js:6:84)
    at verifySignature (D:\fullstack\passkey-authentication\server\node_modules\@simplewebauthn\server\script\helpers\verifySignature.js:20:86)
    at verifyAuthenticationResponse (D:\fullstack\passkey-authentication\server\node_modules\@simplewebauthn\server\script\authentication\verifyAuthenticationResponse.js:157:66)
    at async exports.loginVerification (D:\fullstack\passkey-authentication\server\controllers\challenge.controller.js:182:20)

Response ouput

I was trying to finally authenticate the user but this issue came and I'm storing the data on mongodb.

Seeing decodeCredentialPublicKey in the stack trace makes me think that there's something up with the value of authenticator.credentialPublicKey. I can personally confirm that this issue has come up twice before when users of my library combine SimpleWebAuthn with MongoDB:

https://github.com/MasterKale/SimpleWebAuthn/discussions/375#discussioncomment-5538495
https://github.com/MasterKale/SimpleWebAuthn/issues/577

It appears something happens to the credential public key bytes if you don't massage the bytes coming out of MongoDB into a Uint8Array before passing them in as authenticator.credentialPublicKey.
Updating your code to do something like this is likely to resolve your issue:
const result = await verifyAuthenticationResponse({
  // ...
  authenticator: {
    ...userObject.passkey,
    credentialPublicKey: new Uint8Array(
      userObject.passkey.credentialPublicKey.buffer,
    ),
  },
});


Thanks @IAmKale for solving the issue, I was trying from last 3hrs but didn't find any solution and your provided solution worked for me.

I'm glad to hear it! Don't forget to mark this as the solution to help save others from this problem in the future ✌️

yes IAmKale is absolutely correct
but lets see how to better structure your MongoDb schema for passkey and everything that it entails including the public key
Passkey MongoDB schema
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoosePaginate = require("mongoose-paginate-v2");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const passkeySchema = new Schema(
  {
    // Reference to the user associated with the passkey
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: true,
      index: true,
    },
    // Unique identifier for the credential
    webAuthnUserID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
    },
    // Unique identifier for this credential
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    // Public key for authentication signature verification
    publicKey: {
      type: Buffer,
      required: true,
    },
    // User-friendly name for the device
    deviceName: {
      type: String,
      default: "Unnamed Device",
    },
    // Usage counter for preventing replay attacks
    counter: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      default: 0,
    },
    // Allowed transport methods for the credential
    transports: [
      {
        type: String,
        enum: [
          "ble",
          "cable",
          "hybrid",
          "internal",
          "nfc",
          "smart-card",
          "usb",
        ],
      },
    ],
    // Type of device (e.g., single-device or multi-device)
    deviceType: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["singleDevice", "multiDevice"],
      default: "singleDevice",
    },
    // Backup status of the credential
    backedUp: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    // Metadata information about the device/browser used
    metadata: {
      browserName: String,
      browserVersion: String,
      deviceType: String,
      platform: String,
    },
    // Status of the passkey
    status: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["active", "revoked", "suspended"],
      default: "active",
    },
    // Timestamp of last usage
    lastUsed: {
      type: Date,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

passkeySchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Passkey", passkeySchema);


You probably would want to have a service for your passkey model to make your code cleaner and easier to read
const passkeyModel = require("../models/passkey.model");

/**
 * Create passkey
 * @param {Object} passkey
 * @returns Passkey
 */
const createPasskey = async (passkey) => {
  const createdPasskey = await passkeyModel.create({
    ...passkey,
  });
  return createdPasskey;
};

module.exports = {
  createPasskey,
};

So in your verifyRegistration when you are good to go you can save your passkey in the db
  //this we console logging the public key just to see it 
  console.log("public key", credential.publicKey);

  //the process of converting the Uint8Array toi a buffer that mongodb is cool with 
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(credential.publicKey);
  const buffer = Buffer.from(uint8Array);

  // Create new passkey in database
  await createPasskey({
    user: req.user?._id,
    webAuthnUserID: registration?.user?.id,
    id: credential.id,
    // storing the converted buffer
    publicKey: buffer,
    counter: credential.counter,
    transports: credential.transports || [],
    deviceType: credentialDeviceType || "platform",
    backupState: credentialBackedUp || false,
    deviceName,
  });

and finally in your verifyAuthentication when you want to authenticate the user in
// taking into consideration that existingPasskeys holds the passkey that we saved in the db initially for this user
//converting the public key back to unit8Array
  const backToUint8Array = bufferToUint8Array(
    existingPasskeys.publicKey
  );
  
  const verification = await verifyAuthenticationResponse({
    response: credential,
    expectedChallenge: registration.challenge,
    expectedOrigin: origin,
    expectedRPID: rpID,
    credential: {
      id: existingPasskeys.id,
      //using the converted value 
      publicKey: backToUint8Array,
      counter: existingPasskeys.counter,
      transports: existingPasskeys.transports,
    },
  });

  const { verified } = verification;
  //once the value got verified is true we can go on with our daily business


